# Does a random sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$ imply $n > 1$?

Tags: self-study, notation

I am calculating the variance for an estimator which is a function of a random sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$. However, if $n=1$, then $E(\theta^2) = \infty$ and the variance is infinite. Can I assume $n > 1$ due to the random sample definition $X_1, \dots, X_n$ or does this also include the random sample of {$X_1$}?

Comment: If $n=1$ then the sample variance is zero and not infinite $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2 = \frac{1}{1} (x_1 - \bar{x})^2  = 0$$

Comment: The usual sample variance has a $n-1$ denominator, giving infinity.

Comment: What is "$\theta$"??

Comment: @MichaelM I think the point is that $x_i-\bar x=0$.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because I find it incomprehensible without some explanation of what "$\theta$" means and I can think of several different interpretations requiring different answers.  It would also help to know whether you consider the $X_i$ to be scalars or whether they are possibly vector-valued.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I assume $n > 1$ due to the random sample definition $X_1, \dots, X_n$ or does this also include the random sample of {$X_1$}?

Technically a single observation is a sample as well.

The notation $X_1, \dots, X_n$, which implies at least two elements, is for convenience. It is used because often, in practice, a sample has more than a single observation (and the implied $n > 2$ or $n > 1$ does not matter).

The notation implies more than one observation (and it even also implies more than two observations because the dots make no sense, $X_1, \dots, X_2$, when $n=2$). But often this is not intentional. The notation is not used to restrict the size of the sample. The notation is used for convenience.

---

> However, if $n=1$, then $E(\theta^2) = \infty$ and the variance is infinite.

In your particular case, a population or sample variance, it would make sense to use a sample of at least size 2. But that is a different story than the use of the notation ("due to the random sample definition ") that you mention.

Comment: So are you saying that I can the notation $X_1, \dots X_n$ implies $n > 1$? I would expect the author of the question to have stated $n \ge 1$ or $n > 1$ but seeing as no such information is provided, I am left wondering if it is implicitly provided by another statement.

Comment: @s5s let's fill it in if $n=1$ does the following make sense? $$X_1, \dots , X_1$$ no it doesn't.

Comment: The expression $$X_1,\dots,X_n$$ has two purposes. **1** It explains that there is a sample with several elements, and **2** in addition it explains that the elements are expressed with a superscript $X_i$. So the expression is a shortcut for a lot of words. It is to explain that we have a set of numbers...

Comment: ... Alternatively instead of the shortcut expression *"Let there be a sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$"* we could use a phrasing like *"Let there be a sample $S$ with $X_i$ an element in the set $S$ where $i$ denotes the $i$-th observation in the sample. So if the cardinality of the set is one then we can describe the set as $S = \lbrace X_1 \rbrace$, if the cardinality is two then we can use $S = \lbrace X_1, X_2 \rbrace$ and more generally when the cardinality is $n$ (except when $n= 1$) then $S = \lbrace X_1, \dots,  X_n \rbrace$ where the dots represent all the $X_i$ between $i=1$ and $i=n$."*

Comment: And I forgot to mention that $i$ is a positive integer in the range $[1,n]$. So no $X_{\sqrt{2}}$ and every integer is included so $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{11}$ does not mean the sample $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_5 , X_7, X_{11}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally reasonable to get an infinite variance of an estimator, such as the variance of $\bar X$ for a distribution like $t_2$.

Further, estimator variances definitely make sense for samples of just $1$, such as $\text{var}\left(\bar X\right)=\sigma^2$ for $X\sim N\left(\mu,\sigma^2\right)$.

Therefore, this does not seem like a problem. You just have infinite variance when you observe one point.